# Which attribute replace for “layout_constraintGuide_Percent” at Android-Studio

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

I used constraint layout **Android Studio 2.3.1** with **`constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4`** dependency before, but now I am using `'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'`, **layout_constraintGuide_Percent** attribute is not exists.

Which attribute replace for `layout_constraintGuide_Percent`?

my code:

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline_vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_Percent="0.8"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="50dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the attribute with this

```
app:layout_constraintGuide_percent
```

Comment: So you want new answer?